# Error while comparing two raster layer in R

Tags: raster, r, interpolation, spatial-statistics

I have got a geographic point distribution with N prehistoric settlements with a size of x and want to compare the distribution with an economic simulation, which produces M settlements (Usally N > M). I've done about 110 runs with different parameters and now I'm looking for a best-fit model. Therefore I calculate the Kernel Density Estimation for the real settlemts (x_dens), the simulation results (y_dens) and for the M-biggest real settlements (xM_dens) and want to compare the cell values of two kernel density estimations in R.

As a first step, i am using the function density.ppp from the Package "spatstat".

```
x_dens <- density(x_ppp, sd, eps=rw, edge=TRUE, at="pixels")
x_ras <- raster(x_dens, crs="+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0")

y_dens <- density(y_ppp, sd, eps=rw, edge=TRUE, at="pixels")
y_ras <- raster(y_dens, crs="+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0")

xM_dens <- density(xM_ppp, sd, eps=rw, edge=TRUE, at="pixels")
xM_ras <- raster(xM_dens, crs="+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0")
```

The next step includes the calculation of the cell differences for x with xM, to see which would be minimum error for my M simulated settlements:

```
xxM_comp <- sqrt(((x_ras - xM_ras)^2 / x_ras))
xxM_comp [!is.finite(xxM_comp )] <- 0
xxM_comp_result <- sum(xxM_comp @data@values)
```

As a next step, i'm doing the same for my Y-simulated settlements:

```
xy_comp <- sqrt(((x_ras - y_ras)^2 / x_ras))
xy_comp [!is.finite(xy_comp )] <- 0
xy_comp_result <- sum(xy_comp @data@values)
```

To evaluate the best-fit model, i caluclate:

```
results <- xy_comp_results/xxM_comp_result
```

xy_comp shall result in a new raster layer, which shows the differences in both point pattern, but the resulting cell values are enormously high at some points and as a consequence xy_comp_result has a illogically high value. It is due to the fact, that some pixel values of x_ras much to small compared with y_ras. Do you have got any suggestions, how to solve this problem. I've tried to remove outliers, but I did not get proper results.

[image: xy_compare]

The methodology is described in D. Stelder, Where do Cities Form? A Geographical Agglomeration Model for Europa, Journal of Regional Science 45 (4), 2005, 657-679 (http://www.regroningen.nl/stelder/doc/JRS_nov2005_c.pdf) Starting with page 669.

Comment: What about extent and resolution of your rasters (x_ras,y_ras)? You need x_ras,y_ras to have the same extent and resolution, and then if you only want the differences you can try diff_rast = x_ras - y_ras.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
x_ras and y_ras have got the same resolution as well as the same extent.

I need the result of x_comp_result for further calculation. I want to compare a prehistoric settlement pattern with the results of an (economic) simulation.

Comment: Have you thought of standard deviation? You can create a stack with your rasters: stack_rasters=stack(x_ras,y_ras). Then you can use the standard deviation like this: difference=calc(stack_rasters, fun=sd). (not tested).

Comment: Might be a very good idea, but now i get following error: 
"Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable): unable to find an inherited method for function ‘calc’ for signature ‘"RasterStack", "numeric"’"

Comment: I believe that you are, in fact, using a ppp object and the density function from spatstat, not raster. This is not a standard KDE and should not be treated as such. The results are an isotropic density and represent the intensity function and an expectation of the spatial process. Across scales, these intensity functions are not comparable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! You are absolutely right - i'am using the density function from spatstat with a ppp object. Do you have any idea, how to adjust the scales?

Comment: Is there any reasons why you are not directly comparing x_dens with y_dens and apply the projection to the ppp ie. before density?

Comment: No, not really, but there is not difference to the resulting raster layer.

I've now used kde.points from GISTools with the SpatialPointsDataFrame, but the resulting pixel values are enourmesly high, too.

Comment: As previously stated, KDE's are not comparable across scales. There is no way to separate the effect of the kernel function from the actual spatial process of the point pattern. The sigma (bandwidth) can shift the spatial process from a 1st order to a 2nd order approximation, which can start indicating nonstationarty. This is a huge issue when trying to elucidate meaning from the comparison. You can integrate the volumes of multiple KDE's but, not draw inference.

Comment: I looks like the methodology outlined in  Stelder (2005) is creating a uniform Gaussian distribution, with equal-peaks,  for each location (city) and not a density estimate. You issue is related to the variation in the density estimate where peaks are wildly different.

Comment: Is there a possibility to compute such a distribution with R?

Answer (score 3):

I am curious as to why you are not approaching this problem using a point pattern analysis? It is apparent that you are after a multiscale comparision but, it is not clear as to what end or what type of supported inference would be made. The type of standardization that your are attempting is hinting that a PPA would be a more supported methodology.

Depending on your hypothesis, I would highly recommend taking a look at the Geits-Ord or Ripley's-K statistic(s). If you have covariates there are correlogram methods implementing the partial Mantel test, which if permuted, support exploratory analysis. Another option for a marked point process would be the family of scan statistics, which can be specified using assumed point process distributions (ie., Poisson, Gaussian, Binomial) and as a multiscale model. All of these methods provide a spatially lagged (multiscale) evaluation of the spatial process and avoid many of the issues associated with kernel density estimates, which is never really considered a supported inferential method. For a robust inference you could formalize a point process model, in a hierarchical Bayesian framework (MCMC), using the estimated intensity function.

Now, if I have misunderstood and you, in fact, want to integrate the volume of two kernel density estimates you could follow one of the methodologies presented in Hurlbert (1978) that provides mathematical definitions for integrating niche volume overlap. The equations are relevant to any volume integration and the paper is available on [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1936632?Search=yes&resultItemClick=true&searchText=The&searchText=Measurement&searchText=of&searchText=Niche&searchText=Overlap&searchText=and&searchText=Some&searchText=Relatives&searchUri=%2Faction%2FdoBasicSearch%3FQuery%3DThe%2BMeasurement%2Bof%2BNiche%2BOverlap%2Band%2BSome%2BRelatives%26amp%3Bacc%3Doff%26amp%3Bwc%3Don%26amp%3Bfc%3Doff%26amp%3Bgroup%3Dnone&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Hurlbert, S.H., (1978) The Measurement of Niche Overlap and Some Relatives. Ecology 59(1):67-77

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I think, that i was looking for the mantel test all the time. I've tried to use it, but i've got a distant matrix with different numbers of rows and columns. Is there a way to perform a mantel test with a n*m-matrix?

Comment: What have you tried? You do not need a symmetric row/col matrix for a Mantel or partial Mantel. The package mpmcorrelogram supports Mantel and partial Mantel tests and correlograms.

Comment: I've used mantel from the ade4 package (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/mantel_test.htm), but with mpmcorrelogram everything works - thanks a lot!